# How can I count all stored cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies

In the browser settings (firefox, chrome) I can see a list of my cookies but not the total number. I'm working on a visualization in JavaScript (D3.js) and would like to add the cookie count.

The only option I have found so far is to write an AddOn, log the length of [cookies.getAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/getAll) and add this number in my visualization. Because this number is constantly changing I'm looking for an easier way to get the number of my cookies using JavaScript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A script that runs on a web page is limited to accessing information related to the page's own origin (a domain, plus scheme and port). By design, for reasons of security, we do not want some `arbitrarysite.foo` to be able to know any information about the user's cookies for, e.g., `gmail.com`. The cookie information of `gmail.com` falls under the exclusive purview of scripts running on `gmail.com`. (There can be exceptions made in both directions on a per-cookie basis -- a cookie may be specially marked for third-party visibility or may be marked not to be visible to scripts at all -- but per-origin exclusivity is the general rule.) therefore, it is not possible for a script running on a normal web page within a particular origin to aggregate cookie information across all origins.

Indeed, writing a browser extension is your best bet. Unlike web pages, extensions can be given special permissions, because users actively opt-in to installing them and proactively grant them permissions. The `cookies.getAll()` extension API seems suitable for your needs. If you supply no filters, it appears to collect all available cookies. However, MDN notes a significant behavioral difference for Edge:

> If no URL is provided, cookies are retrieved only for URLs in currently opened tabs. In Chrome, this gets all cookies on a user's machine.

Considering other browsers (Firefox, Opera) do not carry a similar note, I infer that they get all cookies as well, like Chrome.